# ¿Existe alguna función más fiable que setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo entendido (y comprobado) que setInterval no es capaz de producirse al tiempo fijado de forma exacta, ¿Existe alguna otra función que sí que sea capaz de hacerlo? En caso contrario, ¿Cómo podría hacer un ajax para actualizar la función?

Comment: Al parecer el problema es tu petición ajax que demora más de lo que piensas, por ende tus llamadas repetitivas al servidor "no toman el tiempo fijado".

Comment: ningún lenguaje o librería _per se_ es capaz realizar una tarea en un momento especifico, para hacerlo se requiere soporte de hardware capaz de ejecutar una RTI (o Interrupción en tiempo real) y esto de por si, tiene aplicaciones muy especificas, el desarrollo web no necesita ese tipo de precision.

Comment: Gracias a ambos

Comment: @IvanSoler Quizás si actualizas la pregunta con lo que estás intentando obtengas una mejor respuesta al problema. Haz oído hablar del [problema XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Es cuando piensas que necesitas X para resolver Y pero al final descubres que la solución a tu problema es mucho más sencilla u otra completamente diferente. Ocurre cuando preguntas por la solución en lugar de preguntar por el problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el navegador puedes usar [resquestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame), esta funcion se ejectura hasta un maximo de 60 veces por segundo.

Dentro de esta funcion puedes "preguntar" el tiempo en milisegundos con `new Date()` o `Date.now()`, y compararlo con una marca de tiempo que tu elijas.

Cunado el tiempo en milisegundos sea mayor a tu marca de tiempo entonces ejecutaras el código que corresponde a esa marca de tiempo.

con esto tendrias un margen de error de `1000/60 = 16.6` milisegundos, que en el 99% de los casos es suficiente.

Comment: Qué bueno Cristyan, voy a indagar en el asunto! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Nada te puede garantizar que algo se va a ejecutar en determinado milisegundo exacto. Para la mayoría de los casos setInterval es suficientemente bueno. Para los demás casos Javascript no es el lenguaje adecuado.

Comment: Gracias, me comentan más arriba que no hay ningún lenguaje capaz de realizar esta tarea así que supongo que me rendiré...

Answer (score 0):

Para estar mas seguro debes usar **web workers**, con el fin de ejecutar procesos sin afectar tanto la página.

http://maximilianschmitt.me/posts/setinterval-settimeout-slows-down-on-tab-change/